# MySQL POLYGON query no results

Tags: mysql, point-in-polygon

Database table with a POINT datatype. I can't get any results from a MySQL POLYGON query. Any idea what I am doing wrong? The polygon is closed.

```
id  location
1   POINT(-37.816652 144.964595)    
2   POINT(-37.788132 144.931183)
3   POINT(-37.811291 144.985916)
4   POINT(-37.8389571 144.9656531000001)
5   POINT(-37.851038 144.993205)
6   POINT(-37.8029679 144.9501126)

/* 
 north = -37.711586434367305
 east = 145.45740074179685
 south = -37.92854972934211
 west = 144.6142000582031
*/

SELECT * FROM `properties` WHERE Contains (GeomFromText('POLYGON((145.45740074179685, -37.711586434367305, 144.6142000582031, -37.711586434367305, 144.6142000582031, -37.92854972934211, 145.45740074179685, -37.92854972934211, 145.45740074179685, -37.711586434367305))'), location)

SELECT * FROM `properties` WHERE Contains (PolygonFromText('POLYGON((145.45740074179685, -37.711586434367305, 144.6142000582031, -37.711586434367305, 144.6142000582031, -37.92854972934211, 145.45740074179685, -37.92854972934211, 145.45740074179685, -37.711586434367305))'), location)
```

Comment: Your WKT looks wrong to me.  It should be `POLYGON((X Y, X Y...` rather than `POLYGON((X, Y, X, Y...`, shouldn't it?  (Also, the values seem transposed, as @e4c5 suggests.)

Comment: That's it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have got your cordinates in the wrong order.

```
GeomFromText('POLYGON((-37.711586434367305,145.45740074179685,
  -37.711586434367305, 144.6142000582031,  ....)))
```

Also Contains has been deprecated. better to use MBRContains.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I swapped the coordinates and used MBRContains but still no results.

Comment: how about ST_Contains instead? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-contains

Comment: Still no results with ST_Contains